# CSIRT Softwares

Tags: incident-response, software, incident-analysis

I'm wondering what kind of software Computer Security Emergency Response teams use to manage their work? For example to catalog incidents, responses and manage risks.

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Exchange Daniel! Unfortunately, questions for product recommendations tend to fizzle out after a very short period of time as it's especially hard to keep up with the industry, it's made harder by the sheer amount of tools out there, as such as we tend not to allow product-recommendations here as they become obsolete in a really short amount of time, due to this I am [flagging](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TheHive for security incident management: https://thehive-project.org/
and MISP for threat intel sharing: http://www.misp-project.org/
And for a full list: https://github.com/meirwah/awesome-incident-response#incident-management